# Improving Search Algorithem using Regex in CoreData?

Tags: swift, regex, core-data

I'm transitioning from a SQLite implementation to CoreData.

In SQLite, searches are fairly limited. In a typical search, for a string like "card", I would want to know if any members of a set of letters like [n,l,j,x], would be a valid part of a word, or a whole word, in a stored dictionary of strings.

So, in the example above, I would have to look for `"nard","lard","jard","xard"` and then repeat that process for each subsequent position in the string: `"cnrd","clrd","cjrd","cxrd"`.

This is slightly controlled by the fact that I only need a single match per position in the target string to "qualify" it, so I can search for `"nard","cnrd","cand","carn"`, and if I get a match at any point, I can mark that point in the target word as qualified, and focus on the other targets.

Thus, if I got a match at "nard" and no other matches, the next loop might check `"clrd","cald","carl"`, and so on. If I got matches at `"nard","cand"`, the next loop would be `"clrd","carl"` : you get the idea.

Does CoreData, which I know under the hood is just SQLite anyway, offer any more advanced features that would allow me to improve the default algorithms I've used, perhaps using regex? Can a pattern like `\^{3}[nljx]\` be somehow used?

I'm not at the point where I'm writing the code to experiment in this direction, so anything people can point me to is great.

Comment: Some documentation [from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) and a [quick guide](https://nspredicate.xyz) for predicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a SQLite store with Core Data, predicates are translated into SQLite code and executed in SQLite. Predicates therefore have SQLite's limits on what's possible. Core Data can use other store types with different capabilities and limitations-- for example, you can use a predicate that's any arbitrary block of code, but the entire persistent store gets loaded into memory all the time. Whether one of those would work for you depends on how much data you have.

Comment: that's kind of what I was expecting: so the upshot is, I may have a way to create a predicate that does things that SQLite can't do, but in the end I might just as well do things like filter the DB results programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a predicate with `NSMatchesPredicateOperatorType` to do regex searching. SQLite doesn't support regexes directly, but Core Data registers a custom `NSCoreDataMatches` function to do the work without bringing everything into memory.